# How do I do this in angular? I have a $scope.photos, but I want the h1 to show the category if it exists otherwise display "Explore"

Tags: angularjs

In React, I would have just done something like

```
<h1>{this.props.photos ? this.props.photos.category : 'Explore'}</h1>
```

How can I achieve the same in angular?

When I try something like this in my controller, I get `category is not defined`.

`$scope.photos.category = $scope.photos ? $scope.photos.category : 'Explore';`

Comment: If $scope.photos is undefined, you're trying to set $scope.photos.category to 'Explore'. How could that work, since $scope.photos is undefined? This has nothing to do with angular. It's just  JavaScript. Not sure why you're doing that in the controller anyway. You can just do `{{ photos.category || 'Explore' }}`.

Comment: wow thanks.  my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $scope.photos is undefined, you cannot assign value to $scope.photos.category, for that photos need to be defined.
However if you want to show category you could do:

```
$scope.category = $scope.photos ? $scope.photos.category : 'Explore';
```

and then used:

```
<h1>{{category}}</h1>
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it has solved your problem.. :)